# Terminal which remembers its state

Tags: 10.10, gnome-terminal, konsole

Having used `gnome-terminal` I noticed that it does not remember its state, once closed. I would like a terminal which remembers its state, this includes the title of the tabs and the current directory in which I was. IIRC the `konsole` of KDE3 did this. So I installed `konsole`
 (the current version which comes with Ubuntu 10.10) however it does not seem to remember its state either. :(

Answer (score 2):

My only recommendation for this is to use something like [GNU Screen](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/screen)

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

which is a terminal multiplexor which will maintain states after the terminal has been disconnected. It can also be configured to save it's state to disk to maintain sessions between restarts.

Comment: I know about screen, so maybe I should install it again..

Comment: How can I set the name of a shell in screen using a command or a variable?

Comment: ctrl-a followed by shift-a

Answer (score 1):

Enabling Gnome to "remember currently running applications" provides a partial workaround, if it doesn't interfere with other parts of your workflow.

It remembers gnome-terminal screen profiles, locations, and directories upon logout.
(It will remember other running applications as well, which may or may not be a good thing for a given situation.)

There may be some wrinkles, but I've used this happily on one of my work systems where I have, at every login, a gnome-terminal starting at a deep documentation build directory, in a tiny, tiny font ; other windows running different font/color/directory profiles ; and a browser open to the html version of the doc that's set in the terminal path.

If you want to try this, you'd go to

*System > Preferences > Startup Applications*

then on the *Options* tab ,select "Automatically remember running applications when logging out" .

[image: checkbox on 'Automatically remember running applications when logging out']

Counterintuitive, but sometimes very useful.

Alternatively, you can set it to remember your current set-up, instead of doing this automatically from logout.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Guake](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/guake).

Comment: Nah they shall just fix gnome and kde terminal.